# Symfony messenger won't always restart

Tags: symfony, systemd, symfony-messenger

I'm currently working on a Symfony 4 application which use [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html) to handle some background jobs with a dedicated worker.

I run the worker using systemd v241 with the following configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Symfony Worker
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitBurst=0

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/symfony-app/current
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bin/console messenger:consume async --memory-limit=512M --time-limit=3600'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -lc 'bin/console messenger:stop-workers'
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

As written in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html#deploying-to-production), the worker must not run forever so it restart every hour or every time it reach the memory limit of 512M.

My problem is that it doesn't always restart. Sometimes it does but sometimes it doesn't and the only thing I get is a `Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM` in my logs.

Any idea why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Lingering](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) weren't enable on the user responsible of starting the service. Enabling it has solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for adding the solution instead of just writing 'nvm, found the solution'